# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Scanner to boolean

Tags: java

I am making a basic currency converter which takes a users choice of currency and converts the amount, obviously not finished as I have ran into this problem. Help and pointers would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Converter {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double PLN;
        double GDP;
        System.out.println("Which currency do you wish to convert?");
        System.out.println("Press a corresponding number");
        System.out.println("1. Great British Pound (GDP) £");
        System.out.println("2.Polish zloty (PLN) zl");

        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (option = 1){            

        }       
    }   
}
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from Scanner to boolean
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Scanner
>       at Converter.main(Converter.java:14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be more like

```
Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = option.nextLine();

if (userInput.equals("1")){            
    // ...
}
```

A few things wrong here:

1. Testing for equality is `==`, NOT `=`. You're trying to assign `1` to the `Scanner` object.
2. The `Scanner` *itself* is not actually a string. You need to call `readLine` on it.
3. Even if the `Scanner` was a string, you can't compare a `String` to an `int`.
4. You need to use `.equals` for strings, since `==` in Java always compares by *reference*, not by value. `==` basically means "are these two objects **the exact same object**," not "do these two objects look the same."

An alternative way is to use `nextInt`:

```
Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!option.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Bad input"); // print an error message
    option.nextLine(); // clear bad input
}
int userInput = option.nextInt();
if (userInput == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Also note that you can use a `switch` statement for cases like these:

```
int userInput = option.nextInt();
switch(userInput) {
case 1:
    // the user input was 1
    break;
case 2:
    // it was 2
    break;
// ...
default:
    // it was not any of the cases
}
```

You can use `switch`es on strings, but only in Java 7 or above.

Comment: @SLaks Whoops, too much JS and Ruby on my part ;)

Comment: i like your 3rd point that is associated for your example cause you use `readLine` cause he could use `nextInt` and point 3 is pointless

Answer (score 0):

You could.... change your initial condition from this:

```
if (option = 1) //??
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("Enter int: ");
if ((option.nextInt()) == 1)
//do something
```

Comment: It is better to store result of `nextXXX` somewhere in case there will be more `if`s using users data. Otherwise each of these `if`s will ask user for input.